# Import of class and use of a method in it is not working in groovy contract test script

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, groovy, spring-cloud-contract

```
Mygroovyfile.groovy 
-------------------------
org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract.make {
    description('''
        given:
            blah blah
        when:
              blah blah
        then:
             blah blah
    ''')
    request {
       method 'GET'
       headers {
        contentType(applicationJson())
        header('Authorization': 'BEARER blahZblah')
      }
      url value(consumer('blah blah link'), producer('blah blah link'))
    }
    response {
      status 200
      body([

blah blah blah "rest body of the stub"                  
           links: [
             'self': [
                 'href': "blah blah link"
              ]
           ]
        ])
        testMatchers {
            jsonPath("\$.links['self']['href']", byCommand('assertThatSelfLinkMatches($it, "blah blah link")'))
        }  
       headers {
         contentType(applicationJson())
       }
    }
}

    import companybuild.customlib.GPT;

String GPT(gpt){

 return companybuild.customlib.GPT(gpt);
}

and when I do the maven clean install it's giving me an error 

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:1.2.1.RELEASE:generateTests (default-generateTests) on project room-pricing-service: Execution default-generateTests of goal org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:1.2.1.RELEASE:generateTests failed: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
[ERROR]service\src\test\resources\contracts\Mygroovyfile.groovy: 108: unable to resolve class companybuild.customlib.GPT
[ERROR]  @ line 108, column 2.
[ERROR]         import companybuild.customlib.GPT;
[ERROR]     ^
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 1 error
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

we are currently writing contract test that actually uses spring cloud contract and we have a base java class that expands and uses the groovy file and I'm encountering a problem with imports with groovy

I would like to import my company built a custom jar which has some java class that has some methods Now problem is I would like to access in MyGroovyFile.groovy

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole flow is described in the documentation very thoroughly. Please read this chapter https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR3/single/spring-cloud.html#_extending_the_dsl . You can also check the samples https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/ where we have exactly the same scenario.

A separate module https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/master/common

referenced on the classpath to help with autocompletion

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>beer-common</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

referenced on the plugin's classpath

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-contract.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <packageWithBaseClasses>com.example</packageWithBaseClasses>
            <baseClassMappings>
                <baseClassMapping>
                    <contractPackageRegex>.*intoxication.*</contractPackageRegex>
                    <baseClassFQN>com.example.intoxication.BeerIntoxicationBase</baseClassFQN>
                </baseClassMapping>
            </baseClassMappings>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>beer-common</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

and in the DSL

````
package contracts.beer.rest

import com.example.ConsumerUtils
import com.example.ProducerUtils
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
    description("""
Represents a successful scenario of getting a beer
```
given:
    client is old enough
when:
    he applies for a beer
then:
    we'll grant him the beer
```
""")
    request {
        method 'POST'
        url '/check'
        body(
                age: $(ConsumerUtils.oldEnough())
        )
        headers {
            contentType(applicationJson())
        }
    }
    response {
        status 200
        body("""
            {
                "status": "${value(ProducerUtils.ok())}"
            }
            """)
        headers {
            contentType(applicationJson())
        }
    }
````

Comment: Worked Like a Charm. All I forgot was adding the dependency in the plugin and def the method.  Thank you!!! That really helped me soo much.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same with gradle and classes living in same project?